# How to use rsync to backup local folders to an external hard drive with hard links for unchanged files

Tags: hard-drive, backup, external-hdd, rsync

I have two folders in my home directory that I need to backup to an external hard drive. Each folder has some files that should be excluded from the backup, and I have a file named "backup-exclude" in my home directory to specify these exclusions. Here is the directory structure:

```
Home Directory:
- Dir1/
- Dir2/
- backup-exclude
```

I want to use rsync to backup these folders to an external hard drive, and I would like to utilize hard links for unchanged files in order to save space. The external hard drive has the following structure:

```
External Hard Drive:
- Backup/
  - backup-2023-06-10/
    - Dir1/
    - Dir2/
  - backup-2023-06-03/
    - Dir1/
    - Dir2/
```

The file system format of the home directory is ext4, while the external hard drive is formatted as NTFS. The command I currently use to perform the backup is as follows:

```bash
rsync -av \
      --exclude-from=backup-exclude \
      --delete-excluded \
      --delete-after \
      ~/Dir1 ~/Dir2 \
      /external-hdd/Backup/backup-2023-06-10
```

However, I would like to modify this command to make use of hard links to previous backups on the external hard drive. I have attempted the following command, but it did not work as expected:

```bash
rsync -av \
      --exclude-from=backup-exclude \
      --delete-excluded \
      --delete-after \
      --link-dest=/external-hdd/Backup/backup-2023-06-03/ \
      ~/Dir1 ~/Dir2 \
      /external-hdd/Backup/backup-2023-06-10
```

Can someone please provide the correct command to achieve the desired behavior of hard linking to previous backups on the external hard drive?

Comment: I would recommend you download `luckyBackup` from Ubuntu Software. It provides a graphical interface which makes the use of rsync a breeze.

Comment: Hard links cannot be used across volumes (from one disk to anotherl)

Comment: @waltinator, what I mean is that the hard links I want to create should be within the external hard drive itself. When using `rsync`, it should compare the files between the EXT4 file system (the source) and the NTFS file system (the destination on the external hard drive). If there are no differences found, `rsync` should create a hard link from the NTFS file to another file within the same NTFS file system. This is my understanding of how it should work.

Comment: To me, the command looks OK at first sight. Can you indicate what did not work as expected? Sure this will work on ntfs?

Comment: @vanadium I expect that the unchanged files within the "backup-2023-06-10" directory should possess **identical inode numbers** to the files present in the "backup-2023-06-03" directory. However, this is not the observed behavior.

Comment: Read `man hardlink`. It will hard link identical files (and you get to configure what "identical" means), *after* the backup

Comment: So you notice the files are not hardlinked. Then it remains to be seen if this feature of rsync is expected to work with ntfs. Hardlinks are a unix/linux feature whereas ntfs is a file system of MS Windows, which may not by default support linux hardlinks.